# How to find the value in this probability?

Tags: probability, statistics

Let P(n) be the probability of obtaining exactly n heads and n tails when tossing a coin 2n times.
Write down the value of P(n).

$$n!\approx\frac{n^n}{e^n} \sqrt{2\pi n}$$

is good approximation for large n . Use that to find an approximate value for P(n) for large n of the form P(n) $\approx C/n^a$ where C and a are constants you should determine.

I'm not sure how sure I work on this question, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @MattiP. Yes I meant 2n times, sorry for the typo.

Comment: Since all outcomes of $2n$ throws are equally likely,
$$
P(n) = \frac{\text{ways of choosing n heads among 2n throws}}{\text{all possibilites}}
$$
All possibilities are of course $2^{2n}$. Can you then calculate the numerator?

Comment: @MattiP. Thx for the quick response. Just to clarify the reason why all possibilities is 2^2n is because both head and tail have the chance of 1/2  so we would double 2n and that leads to 2^2n? I have calculated the numerator and I think it is 184756?

Comment: The set of results from $2n$ coin throws can be though of as a string of $0$'s and $1$'s. 0 is tails, 1 is heads (it doesn't matter which way it is ... ). So for one throw, we have $2$ possibilites. For two throws we have $2\cdot 2 = 2^2$ possibilites. For $2n$ throws, we have how many possibilites?

Comment: Also, if we don't know $n$, how did you get $184~756$ ? It seems like you assumed $n=10$ ...

Comment: Have you written the probability of exactly $n$ heads and $n$ tails from the binomial distribution?  If it says $n!$ or $(2n)!$ then you can then use the suggested approximation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In $2n$ tosses, probability of landing $n$ heads and $n$ tails

$P(nH,nT) = \, ^{2n}C_n \times \frac{1}{2^{2n}},$ where $^{2n}C_n$ is number of ways to choose $n$ heads (and rest are tails) or vice versa.

As $n!\approx\frac{n^n}{e^n} \sqrt{2\pi n},$

For large $n$, $P(nH,nT) = \displaystyle \frac{(2n)!}{n! n!} \times \frac{1}{2^{2n}} \approx \frac{(2n)^{2n} \sqrt{4\pi n}}{e^{2n}} \times \frac{e^n \times e^n}{n^n \times n^n \times 2\pi n} \times \frac{1}{2^{2n}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt {\pi n}}$

So, $C = \frac{1}{\sqrt \pi}, a = \frac{1}{2}$